# Explanation of Modular Frobenius Number Proof

Tags: solution-verification, modular-arithmetic

I'm looking at a proof for the Frobenius number with n=2. It's on page 11 here: [https://cs.uwaterloo.ca/~shallit/Talks/frob14.pdf](https://cs.uwaterloo.ca/%7Eshallit/Talks/frob14.pdf)

I just care about the n=2 case, and I understand how $xy-x-y$ cannot be represented by $ax+by$ and how to extend the proof once you show $ax+by=xy-x-y+1$.

However, I'm unsure of the steps to prove what is given on the top of page 11. It states:

$$c=x^{-1}\ \textrm{mod y}, d=y^{-1}\ \textrm{mod x}$$
$$\textrm{It is a simple calculation to show that}$$
$$(c-1)x+(d-1)y=xy-x-y+1$$

Here is my attempt at working through it:
$$cx+dy=x^{-1}x+y^{-1}y=ny+1+mx+1=ny+mx+2=xy+1$$
$$ny+mx=xy-1$$

My next step is to say that we should set $xy-1=p$ and then say that, by definition as we are finding the Frobenius number, $gcd(x,y)=1$ and thus $sx+ty=1$ is findable by the Extendable Euclidean Algorithm, allowing us to use $psx+pty=p$ to set $n=ps$ and $m=pt$ to show $$psy+ptx=xy-1$$.

This feels far from simple (although admittedly I learned about most of this stuff an hour ago solely to understand the proof) and I'm not sure my modular arithmetic is correct.

Any correction or confirmation would be great!

Comment: I’m not sure I understand your computation. Why would $nx+my+2$ equal $xy+1$? And the trouble is that among your $s,t$, one is negative so you don’t get a solution. A better idea is to see that $(c-1)x+(d-1)y$ is congruent to $1-x$ mod $y$, $1-y$ mod $x$, and thus that it is of the form $Nxy-x-y+1$. But if we choose $0 < c <y$, $0 <d<x$, then $(c-1)x+(d-1)y < 2xy-x-y$ so that $N=1$.

Comment: That helps so much, thank you! I didn't even consider modular congruence or that I'd have a negative coefficient.